Save all posts as if saving manually in wp editor
I have a problem, I am with a new project and I have an acf select field called “operation”, in the frontend it looks like a list of options of a select.
I have done several tests to see how it works and I have noticed that every time I delete it (field “operation”) and I generate it again with the same name, it stops being seen in the frontend and the only way to display it again is to save by hand one by one the posts that have that field, with 20 or 30 post there is no problem, but when someone inserts 10000 post the thing gets very serious and having to update by hand 10000 post is unfeasible.
I have tried sql queries that update to the current date, php from the hooks init and save_post and nothing works.
It must be the way wordpress saves the posts manually from the button that there is no way to replicate it.
Best regards and thank you very much.
function update_all_real_estate_posts() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'real_estate',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );    
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            wp_update_post(array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_modified' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_modified_gmt' => current_time('mysql', 1),
            ));
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'update_all_real_estate_posts');



The snippet you provided doesn't show any ACF fields. Show us the relevant code you are using.
